# Apply homography matrix using Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, opencv

I'm trying to apply a homography matrix produced by OpenCV's findHomography to my images. The problem is that i'd like to apply the transform using core graphics on the iphone as opposed to using warpPerspective in opencv - for performance reasons.

Anyone know how the homography transform relates to coregraphics CATransform3D ?

thanks, T