# How to get rotation, translation, shear from a 3x3 Homography matrix in c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, transformation, homography

I calculated the 3x3 homography matrix and I need to get rotation, translation, shear and scale to use them as parameters in the windows8 media element attributes ?!

Comment: You can start with this link:[find-the-rotation-and-skew-of-a-matrix-transformation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107134/find-the-rotation-and-skew-of-a-matrix-transformation

Answer (score 8):

see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78137/decomposition-of-a-nonsquare-affine-matrix

```
def getComponents(normalised_homography):
  '''((translationx, translationy), rotation, (scalex, scaley), shear)'''
  a = normalised_homography[0,0]
  b = normalised_homography[0,1]
  c = normalised_homography[0,2]
  d = normalised_homography[1,0]
  e = normalised_homography[1,1]
  f = normalised_homography[1,2]

  p = math.sqrt(a*a + b*b)
  r = (a*e - b*d)/(p)
  q = (a*d+b*e)/(a*e - b*d)

  translation = (c,f)
  scale = (p,r)
  shear = q
  theta = math.atan2(b,a)

  return (translation, theta, scale, shear)
```

Comment: why is the normalized homography 2x3 matrix in your input argument?

Comment: @FäridAlijani in my case, it was the homography matrix (H) computed using OpenCV `(H, mask) = cv2.findHomography(ptsA, ptsB, method=cv2.RANSAC)`