# Using opencv 3.0 findHomography perspective transformation matrix for CALayer CATransform3D transformations

Tags: ios, opencv, perspective, catransform3d, homography

I'm currently experimenting with opencv on the iOS platform. The idea is to capture a video feed and then look for an image within that feed. I am correctly detecting the image and would like to use the homography between the known image and the image on screen to transform a CALayer which contains a frame for the image (so that the frame is drawn around the image).

I've calculated a homography between two images using findHomography. I've verified that this homography is valid since using perspectiveTransform to draw a border around an image into a cv::Mat gives me perfect alignment under scaling, translating and rotating the camera in 3D. I would like to use the homography to transform a CALayer (Core Animation on iOS) to draw a HUD over the captures image. This would be used to mark the located image in the camera feed.

I've tried using Tommy's answer from [Converting OpenCV's findHomography perspective matrix to iOS' CATransform3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467724/converting-opencvs-findhomography-perspective-matrix-to-ios-catransform3d) but this did not work. No image was shown on the screen.

Im using a custom CALayer subclass which simply draws a rectangle in its frame. Ive tested this without a transform and it works. When I apply the generated CATransformation3D however, nothing is drawn to the screen.

I've tried to debug this by using Tom's answer from [How to get rotation, translation, shear from a 3x3 Homography matrix in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420693/how-to-get-rotation-translation-shear-from-a-3x3-homography-matrix-in-c-sharp) to calculate the homographys stats but these seem weird: they give rotation in increments of pi/2 and scales of enormous magnitude. Al the while, perspectiveTransform seems to use the found homography matrix perfectly.

Is there some change to opencv 3.0 which made the answers from the above 2 questions stop working? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 3x3 homography is a 2D to plane to plane transformation. According to http://www.thinkandbuild.it/introduction-to-3d-drawing-in-core-animation-part-1/ CATransform3D is a 3D transformation and therefore using a 4x4 transformation matrix. You did try to add a [0, 0, 1, 0] line + row for the missing dimension?

Comment: I did. Did not work however. Using key-value coded property scale.x on the CATransform3D gives wildly variating values even when the camera is barely moving and when openCV is detecting the image correctly

Comment: Max, did you ever solve this problem?  I seem to be walking down the exact same path you are.  I can use all the OpenCV functions to create a homography and translate images (camera frames) perfectly.  But whenever I try to make a CATransform3D to apply to the camera view, I get the same incorrect results you do.